# Qual a melhor forma de fazer replicação de banco de dados?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-access

Tenho uma aplicação em **WPF + MS ACCESS** onde os usuários fazem cadastros, consultas, etc. O servidor principal está localizado em SP, mas temos filiais em RJ, BA, MG, PR, RS, GO, etc, que também acessam a ferramenta. Devido a problemas de conexão nessas filiais, acaba que um simples `SELECT` demora muito para ser executado e a conexão não acaba caindo. Pensamos em replicar esse banco de dados para o PC local e fazer um robô (console) para atualizar tanto a base local quanto enviar as informações para o BD central de SP.

Pensando que o que tenho em mãos é somente o **MS ACCESS** e o **VS2013**, essa é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema? Se não, qual seria uma melhor forma?

Comment: Sugiro repensar o banco de dados a ser usado. MS ACCESS por si só já é lento!

Comment: Minha vontade seria utilizar SQL Server mas não tenho essa possibilidade, a empresa não permite por políticas... preciso fazer isso com ACCESS mesmo.